# Why is this selenium code not working always?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

Why does this works only sometimes? Sometimes it navigates easily and sometimes it gets stuck after selecting a category. I want to click the category button and select notebook then the series button and click "acer one" and then the first model from model menu. But somehow it gets stuck sometimes after category and sometimes after series.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
import urllib.request

PATH = r"D:\Py\Selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/support')


driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/5);")


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/a"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/a"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/a"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/ul/li[1]"))).click()
src = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/img"))).get_attribute("src")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(src),"img.png")

time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
# search.send_keys("m")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure why your code is failing, but i have tried this code which i ran multiple times and it is not failing. Please give it a try and do let me know if you have any issues running this script. Please find the code below -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/support')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Category')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Category')]/following-sibling::ul/li/a[text()='Notebook']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Series')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Series')]/following-sibling::ul/li/a[text()='Acer One']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Model')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Model')]/following-sibling::ul/li[1]"))).click()

src = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/img"))).get_attribute("src")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(src), "img.png")

time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

I have slightly modified your code. Thank You..!

Comment: its giving an error "element not interactable"  with EC.element_to_be_clickabel this error goes but then it starts getting stuck

Comment: can you explain why presence_of_element is better than that?

Comment: I have updated my code .. now try and let me know if it works?

Comment: ok but can we reduce the wait time? will a try : catch: with while loop be a better option?